# animate radial-gradient CSS3 : move from left to right?

Tags: css, animation, background, radial-gradients

I want animate a background with a radial-gradient `radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%)`, to move it from left to right

http://jsfiddle.net/odsb1fjh/2/

how can I do to animate this radial-gradient to move infinite on div from left to right?

I have already try animation and keyframe background-position: left/right bottom; but don't works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"but we can see the border of "square" where is the light radial" - Why use radial background at all, simply use:

```
div
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url(http://frontend.lostboys.nl/presenations/Icons-fonts/img/chrome.png);
  overflow: hidden;
}
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background: linear-gradient(
    90deg,
    rgba(250, 250, 250, 0) 0%,
    rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5) 60%,
    rgba(250, 250, 250, 0) 100%
  );
  -webkit-animation: animation 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
  from {
    left: -250px;
  }
  to {
    left: 250px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```css
div
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(http://frontend.lostboys.nl/presenations/Icons-fonts/img/chrome.png)
}

div:after
  {
     content:'';
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
     background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    background-position: -1500px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-animation: animation 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
    from {background-position: -250px 0;}
    to {background-position: 250px 0;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

or this

```css
div
{
    position:absolute;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: black;
    background-image: url(http://frontend.lostboys.nl/presenations/Icons-fonts/img/chrome.png);
    overflow:hidden
}

div:after
  {
     content:'';
      position:absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
     background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(255,255,255,0.8) 0, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
    -webkit-animation: animation 3s ease-in-out infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation {
    from {left: -250px;}/**you can use translate3d(-250px,0,0)*/
    to {left: 250px;}/** translate3d(250px,0,0)*/
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Good way, but we can see the border of "square" where is the light radial, it's not realy nice to use like it ^^ Can we smooth it?

Comment: Just change the last 100% in the gradient to something below 70%